# Counter always equal to other counter (at all times)

Tags: theorems, counters

I know that `\newcounter{newctr}[oldctr]` will reset `newctr` to 0 whenever `oldctr` is incremented.
How can I have `newctr` to have exactly the same value as `oldctr` at all times?

In other words, how can I specify `newctr` to be **not reset** but **incremented** whenever `oldctr` is incremented?

You may wonder why I need to counters with exactly the same value at all times. It is because I have defined `\subsubsection` to have italic title but straight number:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection
            {\textup{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
```

But then, when I define a `\newtheorem{foo}[subsubsection]{Something}` then the number of the `foo` statement is typeset straight (although I want it to be italic) simply because `\thesubsubsection` contains the `\textup` command. So I thought that if I have another counter `subsubsectionitalics` with the same value as `subsubsection` but with a different `\thesubsubsectionitalics` then my problem is solved, I just need to define the `foo` statement as `\newtheorem{foo}[subsubsectionitalics]{Something}`.

I tried to define a new counter `subsubsectionitalics` with the following `\thesubsubsectionitalics`:

```
\newcounter{subsubsectionitalics}[subsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsectionitalics
            {\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

but it doesn't work: although in the `\thesubsubsectionitalics` command definition I **do not** use the value of the `subsubsectionitalics` counter, I get a zero value nevertheless. (Why?)

Comment: You're approaching the problem from the wrong side. In general, `\the<counter>` should not contain typesetting instructions. Can you please add a minimal document showing the problem?

Comment: If I use \def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.4\linespacing}{-.5ex}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
how can I get the number of the subsubsection in straight and its title in italics, without fiddling with \thesubsubsection?

Comment: That's not adding a minimal document. You marked as correct David's answer, but I still think there are *much better* ways to do what you seem to want and that don't involve abusing the system.

Comment: I agree with @egreg (and I don't say that very often:-)

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\catcode`\@=11
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection
                {\textup{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.4em}{-.5ex}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{This is a title in italics.}
Bla bla.

\end{document}
This is a minimal document. Could you please show me how to obtain the subsubsection number 0.0.1 in roman while the title of the subsection is in italic, without placing \textup into \thesubsubsection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an abuse of the system really, it would be better just to have `\thesubsection` be the number and leave the font changing to your section layout.

but if you go

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@foo\c@subsection
\newcommand\thefoo{\arabic{foo}}
```

then `\thesubsection` and `\thefoo` can be separately specified and incrementing either foo or subsection increments both.

Comment: IIRC the `aliascnt` package by Heiko has an interface for this